# How to do a distinct count of users over rolling 30 days?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019

I am currently trying to count the distinct number of users over a rolling period of 30 days. My table that I am using only stores rows for dates when something has happened. Since I need a value for each day I have created a date-spine where each client has one row per day since 2021-10-01, 90 days before the date that I am actually interested in since I need rolling counts. I have about 5000 clients.

My table which stores the events-data looks like this:
[image]

The date spine-table I have created includes 1.7 million rows and looks like this:
[image]

I need to have a value for each day, even though a user has not done anything for those days like this:

[image]

My query I have is working as I want it to, but is taking way too long when I try to do it for all clients. I am still faily new to SQL Server and would appreciate any tips!

The query is this (Updated, I tried adding index on the DateValue in the temporary table, still very slow):

```
 Create table #DateSpine
    (
        DateValue date,
        ClientID nvarchar(100),
        UserId nvarchar(100)
    );
create nonclustered index idx on #DateSpine (DateValue);

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN TRY

          TRUNCATE TABLE pre.DistinctUsers;
      

    with clients as (
                SELECT distinct
                    ClientId
                FROM dw.Clients
                where ClientId is not null
                
            ),

            date_spine as (
                select
                    d.DateValue,
                    c.ClientId
                from dw.DimDate d
                cross join clients c
                where 
                    d.Datevalue 
                between 
                    (select dateadd(day, -90, min(DateValue)) from dw.CustomerHealthScore)
                and 
                    (select max(DateValue) from dw.CustomerHealthScore)
            ),


            measures as (
            SELECT
                WKEventDate,
                ClientId,
                UserId
            from dw.FactEvents f
            where EventType = 'render created'
            and RenderType = 'full'
            ),

            final as (
            select 
                d.DateValue,
                d.ClientId,
                UserId
            from date_spine d
            left join measures m 
            on
                d.DateValue = m.WKEventDate
            and
                d.ClientId = m.ClientId
            )

            insert into @DateSpine
            select
                DateValue,
                ClientId,
                UserId
            from final


    INSERT INTO pre.DistinctUsersFR(
                    DateValue,
                    ClientId,
                    NoOfUsersFR30DActual,
                    _batchId)
        
            select
                f.DateValue,
                f.ClientId,
                count(distinct f2.BKUserId) as NoOfUsersFR30Actual,
                @BatchId
            from @DateSpine f
            left join 
                @DateSpine f2
            on 
                f.ClientId = f2.ClientId
            and 
                f2.DateValue 
            between 
                dateadd(day, -30, f.DateValue) 
            and 
                f.DateValue
            group by 
                f.DateValue, f.ClientId
```

I have tried a few other solutions as well but none of them yielded the correct result like this one does. However, this is way too inefficient.

Here is the DDL for the DateSpine-table:

```
create table date_spine (
  DateValue date,
  ClientId nvarchar(100),
  UserId nvarchar(100))
```

```
  insert into date_spine (DateValue, ClientId, UserId)
  values 
  ('2021-10-04', '1', 'xyz')
  ('2021-10-04','2',null)
  ('2021-10-05','1',null)
  ('2021-10-05','2','lko')
  ('2021-10-05','2','abc')
  ('2021-10-06','1',null)
  ('2021-10-06','2',null)
  ('2021-10-07','1',null)
  ('2021-10-07','2',null)
  ('2021-10-08','1','asd')
  ('2021-10-08','2','plo')
```

Query plan:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't work with screenshots, provide DDL with same data.
Which section of the query is causing inefficiency?
Include an actual query plan - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/
How big in the `dw.CustomerHealthScore` or `dw.Clients` tables? Have you tried retrieving the MIN and MAX DateValue into variables and using those in the query?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the post with the DDL, and also edited my code where I tried indexing the temp-table. According to the query plan it seems to be a Hash Match taking most of the CPU-cost. I am trying to past the XML-format to the link you provided but getting errors...

Comment: The dw.CustomerHealthScore-table is fairly big with 700k rows, and dw.Clients only has 5k rows. I have not tried retrieving the MIN and MAX DateValues as variables.

Comment: Where are you seeing the `HASH MATCH`?  It can be notorious for poor performance. Seeing the execution plan will really help here

Comment: For some reason when I try to past the query-plan to the link you provided it is giving me errors... But I have updated the post with screenshots.

Comment: execution plan screenshots are partially helpful.
Create a temp table and populate that with the query from the `measures`  expression.
Then remove the `measures` expression and reference the temp table in the `final` expression

Comment: I tried it, and it was actually a little bit slower than before. However, the ```Hash Match``` has a smaller part.